# Ext.Net: Change TextField highlight on validation error

Tags: validation, extjs, textfield

I have TextFiled from Ext.Net library with following markup:

```
<ext:TextField runat="server" ID="TxtFieldGroupName" AllowBlank="false" />
```

The field should be non empty and I've set AllowBlank="false" for prevent empty values in the field.
By default in case field is empty red corner appears, but I want to highlight my field as yellow.
So, how to highlight field instead default red corner when field is empty?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution.

We should define CSS that highlight control with yellow color:

```
.textfield-invalid
        {
            border-color: #FFCC00 !important;
            background-image: none !important;
            background-color: #FFF2D8 !important;
        }
```

and set defined class name in `InvalidClass` attribute:

```
<ext:TextField runat="server" ID="TxtFieldGroupName" AllowBlank="false" InvalidClass="textfield-invalid" />
```